# What Did I Do Wrong When Solving For This 2nd Order Differential Equation? (answered myself)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, recurrence-relations, power-series

$$
\frac{y''}{y'}+y' = f(x)
$$

I set the following to be true:

$$
y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$$

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n
$$

Therefore:

$$
y'' = y'(f(x)-y')
$$

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2} x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(n+1)a_{n+1} x^n] \times \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(b_n - (n+1)a_{n+1})x^n]
$$

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2} x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(b_n - (n+1)a_{n+1})x^n \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)a_{k+1}]
$$
Therefore
$$
(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2} = (b_n - (n+1)a_{n+1}) \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)a_{k+1}
$$

$$
b_n = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} ka_k} + (n+1)a_{n+1}
$$

$$
y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} ka_{k}} + (n+1)a_{n+1})x^n
$$

Now if i set $a_n = 1$

$$
y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k}x^n
$$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
$$

$$
y = \frac{1}{(x-1)^2} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2x^n
$$

$$
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2x^n = \frac{2}{1-x}
$$

Therefore

$$
f(x) = \frac{2x-1}{(x-1)^2}
$$

$$
y = \frac{1}{1-x}
$$

Therefore

$$
\frac{-2(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{2x-1}{(1-x)^2}
$$

Which is true.

Comment: If you're gonna set $a_n=1$, why do you even bother solving a differential equation?

Comment: @Raskolnikov  Just to see if this method works, I was just playing around with it.

Comment: Don't you see that makes no sense at all? You're basically telling that $y$ is the solution of a differential equation. Then when you set $a_n=1$, you're saying what $y$ has to be, irrespective of the differential equation. If you do the math right, you'll come out with some function $f$ for which that works, but that's likely not what solving this differential equation means. It's for $y$ you're supposed to solve, not for $f$. Of course, you did not state that clearly in the beginning, so I'm not even sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: You are supposed to end up with a recursion. You don't make any initial conditions (unless given).

Comment: @Raskolnikov Setting $a_n = 1$ was so i can be sure that this works in the first place. Why would i test a solution on anything harder? When i am solving for y and f(x) to observe how the relationship must be, therefore if i set f(x) to be anything, i already have a basic template for what the relationship will look like.

Comment: Excuse me. Before the line "Now if I set $a_n=1$", you give an expression for $y$ that is basically $y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$, which is not what you had at the beginning. How is that? Or did you actually mean $f=\ldots$?

Comment: @Demosthene I think that was a mistake, Also just realized a few more, thank you

Comment: So all the following derivation, up until "Therefore", is actually for $f$?

Comment: Well, actually, nevermind. You just have to swap your final expressions for $y$ and $f$; but you're still stuck. I agree, with @Raskolnikov, you simply can't set $a_n=1$. Your derivation makes sense, but only if you keep $a_n$ and $b_n$, and try to figure out what they are.

Comment: @Demosthene i have fixed the mistakes, this does actually work and the only reason it did not work was because of errors

Comment: Well done, then. But making arbitrary constraints on $a_n$ only gives you particular solutions, doesn't it?

Comment: @Demosthene Yes, but there are other recurrence relations that can be made using the information given. On wolframalpha the solution is $y = \ln(c_1-\ln(1-x))+c_2$

Comment: Sure. Your solution is fine, by the way. I upvoted it.

Comment: @Demosthene Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that
you took the terms involving $b_n$
out of the summation.
Here is my take.

I'll start at
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2} x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(n+1)a_{n+1} x^n] \times \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(b_n - (n+1)a_{n+1})x^n]$
but use different indices for the summations
on the right.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2} x^n 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (i+1)a_{i+1} x^i \times \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (b_j - (j+1)a_{j+1})x^j\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (i+1)a_{i+1}  (b_j - (j+1)a_{j+1})x^{i+j}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n} (n-j+1)a_{n-j+1}  (b_j - (j+1)a_{j+1})x^{n}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} (n-j+1)a_{n-j+1}  (b_j - (j+1)a_{j+1})\\
\end{array}
$

From this,

$\begin{array}\
(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n} (n-j+1)a_{n-j+1}  (b_j - (j+1)a_{j+1})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} ja_{j}  (b_{n-j+1} - (n-j+2)a_{n-j+2})\\
\end{array}
$

I'll leave it at this.

Comment: My goal when doing this was to make it so I can explicitly represent one coefficient with variables of the other. That way if I know $y$ or $f(x)$ I have a direct corrilation between the two. Therefore by obtaining this I have a solution for any $f(x)$ that has a power series.